# UINavigationController doesn't rotate when presenting child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my [sample project](https://github.com/nico75005/TestNavigationController)

I have two view controllers embedded in a `UINavigationController`. On the first one, there is just a button performing a segue on the 2nd view controller. On the latter, a button dismiss it back to the 1rst view controller.

The 1rst view controller is not allowed to rotate and stays in `Portrait` while the 2nd is allowed to rotate in `Landscape`.

To do so, I added this code in the 1rst view controller:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

and added an extension to `UINavigationController`:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override public func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        if let topViewController = topViewController {
            return topViewController.shouldAutorotate()
        }

        return false
    }

    override public func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let topViewController = self.topViewController {
            return topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
        }

        return .Portrait
    }
}
```

On the 2nd view controller, I add programmatically a label with some autolayout constraints. The label's title show the `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation`.

My problem is the following:

When I put the device on landscape when I'm on the 1rst view controller, it's fine, the layout is laid for `Portrait` but when I tapp the button to present the 2nd view controller, this one stays on `Portrait` instead of switching to `Landscape`.

And bigger problem for me as in my real project I set some constraints depending on the device orientation, the `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` return the `Landscape` position.

What's wrong? Is it a normal behaviour? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()` in the `viewWillAppear` of the 2nd view controller did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample project, you're not updating the label when the device is rotated. You should `override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` Also, Apple recommends that you not use UIDevice orientation but rather just look at the bounds of your view controller's view. For example:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if size.height<size.width {
            label.text = "Landscape"
        } else {
            label.text = "Portrait"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes indeed I forgot to update the label's title but it doesn't change the problem I was pointing. Okay for using the bounds of my vc instead but then, why does apple provide this method if it's to say to not use it?

Comment: What's the problem again? Apple's recommendation is based on the fact that future implement's of multitasking, etc. may make it so your view controller's view orientation is not the same as the device's.

Comment: that UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation was giving me the right orientation  (`Landscape`)while the navigation controller was laid down in the wrong orientation (`Portrait`). A solution I found is to call `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()` in viewWillAppear but I don't understand why I have to do so...

Comment: Yes I agree with the fact that the view controller's view orientation might not be the same as the device orientation. This is my case, I block the rotation on a view controller and its view stays in Portrait while the device is in Landscape. But then, when I change to another view controller, it should rotate as I didn't block any rotation. Then the `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` is right while the orientation of my view controller's view isn't.

Comment: Did you read the description of attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation seems to explain it: "Some view controllers may want to use app-specific conditions to determine what interface orientations are supported. If your view controller does this, when those conditions change, your app should call this class method. The system immediately attempts to rotate to the new orientation."

Comment: Ahah no I didn't to be honest and I should have. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()` seems to not be working when you start your app in landscape. Or more precisely, starting your app in Landscape and calling `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` returns the wrong orientation (Portrait instead of Landscape)

Comment: What do you mean start your app? Like on an iPad or iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: My bad. On iPhones. Can't say about iPad.

Comment: You mean when you push to the second view controller. Do you need the orientation in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No it was more like a `comment`, not related to the sample project. Using `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` fixed my problem but I realised that it didn't fix it when I was running my app from a widget when being in landscape. And I realised that `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` wasn't really the problem but more `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` that was returning the wrong value.